# Does an MSDTC transaction track/rollback file moves across network shares on different servers?

Tags: c#, msdtc

We have an application that uses MSDTC (Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator) to wrap multiple calls to a database. In between these database calls, the application also moves files from one network share to another.

Setting aside the obvious design problems with this approach (long-running file manipulation occurs in the middle of a database transaction)...

I'm troubleshooting an error where the transaction was rolled back after the file movement occurred, but the files cannot be found on the destination network share. **Is it possible that this file movement is tracked as part of the MSDTC transaction, and undone when the transactions is rolled back?**

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: More likely, an exception is occurring before the files are copied and the copy code never executes.

Comment: I've traced the log messages through the code and verified that the file movement completed successfully.

Comment: What server is this running on? Recent Windows Server versions support a transactional file system, which might possibly have enrolled in your ambient transaction.

Comment: Transactional TFS is only local. It won't be transactional on network shares.

Comment: @Nate: I'm sorry. I can't back this up with online proof. I simply never read anything that might imply that MSDTC works over network shares.